# Unable to change proxy settings

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, windows-8.1

From today I don't know what the hell happened? My network adapter is not allowing me to change proxy setting.
[image]

Anyone has got idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple proxy configurations for different protocols, the `Address` and `Port` fields on the main screen will be grayed out. You must click Advanced to modify them. If you only need one protocol to be affected by the proxy, clear the others.